# Не изменяются регистры.Процессор 8086

Tags: массивы, ассемблер, emu8086

У меня есть код,который должен загружать в регистр ax 3 элемент массива mas,но при запуске эмулятора процессора 8086 и встроенного в ней отладчика,содержимое регистров не меняется(не меняются конкретно те регистры,которые я использую в программе).Как я понимаю,при пошаговом выполнении команд мне в левой части окна должны отображаться регистры,которые должны меняться,так как я их использую.Помогите,пожалуйста

```
.8086
.Model flat 
.Stack 100h
.DATA
mas db 12, 2, 7, 3, 2, 0, 21, 9, 0, 16 
.code
mov bx, offset mas
mov ax, [bx+4]
int 21h
end
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если вы остановились на той строке, что подсвечена на картинке, то никаких изменений в регистре `ax` быть и не должно.

Comment: @andybelous  Перейдите на инструкцию int 21h.

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow перешел,никаких изменений,скриншот добавил

Comment: Вообще меня смущает сочетание `.8086` и `flat` :-) Посмотрите в отладчике что именно находится по адресу `DS:0`

Comment: Да, что у вас в памяти по адресу 0700:0004, куда указывает ds:bx+4

Comment: @Mike я добавил скриншот памяти,но я не знаю,то ли оно отображает,что надо

Comment: @Pink Tux я добавил small,ничего не изменилось,скриншот памяти добавил

Comment: @andybelous Явно не то. Обратите внимание, что у вас DS указывает на 0700, а не на 0721 так что ваш mas должен находится там, вот и надо выяснить так ли это.

Comment: @Mike нули там,кажется,но я не уверен,так как не знаю как это точно просмотреть

Comment: Разыщите свой массив в памяти и попробуйте правильно выставить DS.

Comment: @andybelous, если уж вы пишете в `small`, то `ds` нужно инициализировать явно, как-то так (не знаю какой у вас ассемблер): `mov ax, @data // mov ds, ax`

Answer (score 1):

Потому что забыл написать в начале кода

```
mov ax,@data
mov ds,ax
```

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?